# Fourier serie signal approximation

Tags: electrical-engineering, telecommunication, signal-processing

I have to approximate the red function with Fourier harmonics.

[image: ***enter image description here***]

I am calculating complex **Ck** the following way.

[image]

I am not sure what to put for period - **T** (6 or 2pi or what?). What integral **limits** to use (2/6*2pi and 4/6*2pi ??)?
The way I showed on the picture gives me invalid results... so how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If you already know the explicit form of the function $f(x)$, then it's possible to find the periode by solving this equation $f(x) = f(x+P)$.

If you have a graphical representation of the function (finite), maybe by collecting the numerical values or other means then you have to follow the next two steps:

Step one:

**Trivial extension**

Consider the general finite signal $f \in [[a, b) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}]$ with $p= b-a \in \mathbb{R}$ then its trivial extension is:

$$f_{triv} =\begin{cases}f(x)&x\in [a, b)\\ 0& otherwise \end{cases}
$$

Step two:

**Periodic extension**
 $$f_{per}  = \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} f_{triv}(x-mp)$$

and now you can talk about the periodic function and its Fourier representation.

The periode is indeed six.